# SQL Show All Variables in DB Between Specific Dates Which Are Not In DateTime Format

Tags: c#, sql-server, date, datetime

I wanted to display all rows and columns in my DB between specific dates on an aspx web. However, dates are not recorded in date or date time format. And it seems it is not possible to convert them to date format. I try to do this like this;

```
 public DataTable DisplayRecord()
        {
            var reqID = Request.QueryString["MyId"].ToString();

            //Date parsing

            String[] ids = reqID.Split('-');
            String date1 = ids[0];
            String date2 = ids[1];
            String provider = ids[2];

            SqlDataAdapter Adp = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM flightLogs WHERE depDate_depTime=CONVERT(date,depDate_depTime,104) AND depDate_depTime BETWEEN CONVERT(date,'" + date1 + "',104)" +
                " AND CONVERT(date,'" + date2 + "',104)", connection);

            /*SqlDataAdapter Adp = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT F.PNR, C.amount, F.provider, F.depDate_depTime FROM flightLogs F INNER JOIN companyLogs C ON F.PNR = C.PNR"+
                " WHERE F.depDate_depTime=CONVERT(date,F.depDate_depTime,104) AND F.depDate_depTime BETWEEN CONVERT(date,'" + date1 + "',104)" +
                " AND CONVERT(date,'" + date2 + "',104) AND F.provider='" + provider + "' ORDER BY F.depDate_depTime ASC", connection);*/
            DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
            Adp.Fill(Dt);
            FlightMonitor.DataSource = Dt;
            FlightMonitor.DataBind();
            return Dt;
        }
```

But i get this error;

"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Also data in my DB is shown like this;

```
origin destination  deptDate_depTime        PNR    flightno   provider
KBP    AMS          18.09.2015 - 17:35:00   5RQZ43 PS712      Amadeus
ATH    FRA          10.07.2015 - 12:30:00   ZFY8XW PS716      PGS
```

Comment: You database date time format - is it stored as a varchar?  Is this a fixed format?

Comment: yes it is stored as a varchar format.

Comment: Why you saving your `DateTime` values as a string? Why don't you save them in `datetime` or `datetime2` types? https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is a bad idea to store datetime values in varchar columns as you can see.
if you need a specific format, then you should convert it while you are about to display that value to the users.

but to make things working for now, you can change your where clause from this:

```
depDate_depTime=CONVERT(date,depDate_depTime,104)
```

to this:

```
depDate_depTime = convert(datetime, left(depDate_depTime, 10) + ' ' + right(depDate_depTime, 8), 104)
```

Comment: which value should i give to @dt?